# Как я могу увеличить меню и прочее в netbeans?

Tags: java, шрифты, ide, netbeans

[image]

Слишком мелко для меня все что находиться слева, и над кодом, как исправить?

Comment: Начать стоит с настроек размера шрифтов

Comment: А не могли бы Вы в вопрос дописать, о какой операционке идёт речь?

Comment: Windows 10 OS, настроила уже шрифты в tools - options - Font & colors, стал больше только код